# An optimised way to encrypt a set of data to feed a chart

Tags: javascript, encryption

I have a set of data in a .js file that contains values of stock prices from 2013 to 2015, second by second
i use flotchart to update the chart in real time in order to follow the stock price movements instantly.
the problem is that anyone can open the .js file and have a look at the futur prices. I would like to keep the information hidden. Is it possible to do this without having to move my set of data on a server?
if it is not possible, what are my options to do it the best way in order to keep the process smooth?
as i plan to get one new value every second.

Thanks,
Deeprod

Answer (score 0):

One idea is an ajax based pooling approach on a timer.

Depending on the technology you're using a more elegant solution could be a push framework called signalR that can push updates to your client. 
http://signalr.net/